# Form validation javascript not working in Joomla article

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, joomla

I have made a custom form (which you can view here: http://tylypahka.tk/pisteet/pisteet.php) and it uses javascript based form validation. I've tried to embed the following code to a Joomla module with a Flexi content plugin which allows custom code in module.

So, it's working perfectly if I place the module into a proper position (you can test it here: http://tylypahka.tk/index.php/uutiset/78-pysyvae/75-tupapisteet). But if I try to put that exactly same module to an article, for some reason the validation javascript isn't working. I've tried to embed the module via various different plugins but none of them seem to get the javascript working. I have the following code in the module:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://tylypahka.tk/pisteet/pisteet.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="http://tylypahka.tk/pisteet/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#pisteet").validate({
  rules: {
    pisteet: {
      required: true,
      maxlength: 3
    }
  }
  });
  });
</script>

<div id="tupapisteet">
<div id="stylized" class="myform">
  <h1>Tupapisteet</h1>
   <p>Lisää tai vähennä tupapisteitä tuvilta, hyvän syyn kera</p>
        <form method="post" action="#" id="pisteet">

          <label for="nimi" class="label">Oma nimi<span class="small">Kirjoita oma nimimerkkisi</span></label>
          <input type="text" name="nimi" id="nimi" class="required">
          <br><br><br>

          <label for="tupa" class="label">Tupa<span class="small">Valitse tupa</span></label>
          <select name="tupa">
              <option type="text" name="Rohkelikko" id="Rohkelikko" value="Rohkelikko">Rohkelikko</option>
              <option type="text" name="Luihuinen" id="Luihuinen" value="Luihuinen">Luihuinen</option>
              <option type="text" name="Korpinkynsi" id="Korpinkynsi" value="Korpinkynsi">Korpinkynsi</option>
              <option type="text" name="Puuskupuh" id="Puuskupuh" value="Puuskupuh">Puuskupuh</option>
          </select>
          <br><br><br>

          <label for="pisteet" class="label">Pisteet<span class="small">Jos haluat vähentää pisteitä, laita eteen -</span></label>
          <input type="text" name="pisteet" id="pisteet" class="required number" maxlength="10">
          <br><br><br><br>

          <label for="syy" class="label">Syy<span class="small">Kirjoita tähän hyvät perustelut</span></label>
          <textarea type="text" name="syy" id="syy" class="required"></textarea>
          <br><br><br>

          <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Oikeus tapahtukoon!</button>
        </form>
  </div>
```

Does anyone know what could be the problem here? Any suggestions or help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Could you please send the page where it doesn't work ?

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 versions of jQuery running on your site, so I have a strong feeling it might be due to a jQuery conflict.

I'm not sure where you are adding your code but try using the code we use to detect if jQuery is already being loaded. If it isn't, it imports it.

```
<?php
  if(!JFactory::getApplication()->get('jquery')){
     JFactory::getApplication()->set('jquery',true);
     $document = JFactory::getDocument();
     $document->addScript(JURI::root() . "components/your_component/jquery.js");
  }
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately that didn't work. In fact, the validation stopped working in the module, where it worked previously.

Comment: That might be because you still had 2 more versions of jQuery running. Add this code where jQuery is being imported in every location

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work :( It's funny because it works in the actual module, but if I place the module to an article, it stops working. Is there another validation plugin preinstalled in Joomla and it uses the same classes...?

Comment: unfortunately Joomla doesn't use this. There are very few people who ever use this code. We put it in all out jQuery based extensions. Try @Irfan's answer.

Comment: Okay... Well thanks anyway! :) I think I try to modify Chronoforms extension to fit my purposes and try my luck there. Its built in validation should work in articles too *fingers crossed*

Answer (score 0):

I think due to conflict with mootools library your code is not working.Try using `jQuery.noConflict()`.

```
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(document).ready(function(){
        $j("#pisteet").validate({
      rules: {
        pisteet: {
          required: true,
          maxlength: 3
        }
      }
      });
 });
```

Hope this will help.